# Getting Sound with Qemu and Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspbian-jessie, qemu

I successfully set up a current Raspbian (Jessy) with Qemu. But I really need a soundcard. I'm not sure, if the Sound Chip of the Pi is supported by Qemu?

To boot I use the Kernel from https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel

I start the emulation with:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.4.34-jessie -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda raspbian.img -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -soundhw es1370
```

I also tried different QEMU_AUDIO_DRV (Win: dsound, Linux: pa, oss, alsa). But after all there is no sound card available.

Answer (score 1):

- You are not emulating the Raspberry Pi with your command at all, but the "Versatile PB" board. It is only very roughly compatible with common Raspbian Linux images since it is simply different hardware.
- You can try to force Raspbian into cooperating with "Versatile PB". Replacing the Raspberry Pi kernel is a good (and necessary) first step. I believe QEMU supports the Verstile PB soundcard already.